# Connect JMS queue using JNDI with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, jms, jndi

I had a hard time figuring out how to implement a Spring Boot JMS Listener, listening to an ActiveMQ queue within a JBoss application server.
Therefore I choose to post a question and answer it with my final solution, hoping it could save some of you a few hours.

Answer (score 7):

ActiveMQ is supported by Spring Boot autoconfiguration, but since it was inside the JBoss server Spring Boot was failing to connect ActiveMQ. 
In fact you need to define `connectionFactory` and `jmsListenerContainerFactory` beans yourself by doing a lookup on the JNDI provider.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ActiveMqConnectionFactoryConfig {

  @Value("${broker.url}")
  String brokerUrl;

  @Value("${borker.username}")
  String userName;

  @Value("${borker.password}")
  String password;

  @Value("${queue}")
  String queueName;

  private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
  private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";


  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    try {
      System.out.println("Retrieving JMS queue with JNDI name: " + CONNECTION_FACTORY);
      JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
      jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(CONNECTION_FACTORY);

      jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
      jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

      return (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
      System.out.println("Error while retrieving JMS queue with JNDI name: [" + CONNECTION_FACTORY + "]");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error");
    }
    return null;
  }

  Properties getEnvProperties() {
    Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, brokerUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    return env;
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();

    jndiDestinationResolver.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
    factory.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestinationResolver);
    return factory;
  }
```

Then if you want to consume the queue you just define your JMS consumer class with a method annotated with `@JmsListener(destination = "${queue}")`

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "${queue}")
  public void receive(Message message) {
    System.out.println("Received Message: " + message);
  }
```

Hope that helps save a few hours of research ;)

Cheers

Comment: It broke my integration tests though, so I turned it into conditional configuration with @ConditionalOnClass(name = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory")
Thanks man!